# How to disable the disk write cache in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: linux, caching, ubuntu, benchmarking, ubuntu-13.10

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215516/disabling-disk-cache-in-linux) answer I used:
`sudo hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda`
to try and disable the write cache on my ubuntu 13.10 box running on bare hardware. When I run:
`hdparm -i /dev/sda` i get:

```
...
UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
AdvancedPM=yes: unknown setting WriteCache=disabled
Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-3,4,5,6,7
...
```

However, I still get these insanely high write through puts that are higher than my read which leads me to believe my write cache is still active. What is the correct way to disable the write cache on a Ubuntu 13.10 system??? i'm attaching a screenshot of a utility I've written that shows my write bw to be insanely high (2.2GB/s) until the write cache is filled up (looks like 1.2gb). Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: is your tool posted/published somewhere or will you? And what is the meaning of the green and blue lines each?

Comment: The question was answered here: [How to disable the disk write cache in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452606/how-to-disable-the-disk-write-cache-in-ubuntu-13-10/768592)

Comment: @arch Linux tux the green is a running average of all the read or write io in the session. The blue is the average io for the last group of measure referred to as a mark. There is a currently a Java version of this tool published on sourceforce labaled as jDiskMark. https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdiskmark/